# Schengen visa for multiple visits, how to fill out the forms?

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, multiple-entry

I'm planning to travel to France a few times in the next few months (tourist). Since I need a Schengen visa, I just don't know how to fill out the forms (which only have questions about travel dates of ONE single trip).

How do I report that I am traveling a few times, because if I don't they might only give me a single entry visa (or a visa not valid long enough for my next trips). I can only see that I'm requesting a multiple entry visa, nothing else about how long I need it to be valid.

Do I need to provide proof of hotel/flight reservations and travel insurance for all the trips or would the first one suffice?

How do I approach this issue so that I get a Schengen visa for at least 4.5 months? I am applying in the UK at their London application centre.

Comment: Can you maybe link to the actual forms that you are trying to fill out?

Comment: Sure, https://www.tlscontact.com/gb2fr/upload/short_stay_application_form_en.pdf

Answer (score 3):

- Field 24 lets you indicate multiple entries.
- Field 30 should have the date of the last departure. it identifies the overall duration of the visa.
- Provide documents for flights, hotels etc as much as you can. Preferably have an insurance that does not expire before the last departure. Otherwise add a note that you will get additional insurance in time.

Comment: So I don't need to provide details of my specific trips (each arrival and departure from Schengen area) on the forms, I only need to provide the details of the first arrival and last departure, plus as much documentations as I can. Since I don't exactly know the dates of my future trips, can I book fully refundable hotel and flights for approximate dates (so I'll have more documentations) and cancel them after I got the visa?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. I would not even think it is necessary unless you are from a country where they would be typically suspicious that you would end up as a illegal immigrant (Africa & South-east Asia for example). If you are from the US or Canada I would not be too concerned.

Comment: Thanks. I think I am from one of those so-called high risk countries (Iran) but I'm in the UK on a student visa (fully funded PhD), which is valid until 2017. I've had one Schengen visa before by the way, from France two years ago, valid for 1 month, traveled for three days.

Comment: I think if you can show a good history of stays in europe, you will not have issues.

Comment: You are welcome! Please mark the answer as "solved" if you think it is...